# How to center two primefaces buttons using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, primefaces

What I need to do is to center vertically two buttons. I've tried adding div-container with `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto` and it doesn't work. Also these buttons move up and down when scrolling the page to be always visible.

What I have at the moment is:

```js
    <h:outputScript>
        var buttons_div = document.getElementById("search-and-clear-btns");
        var b_search = document.getElementById("search");
        var b_clear = document.getElementById("clear");
        var vertical_position = 0;
        if (pageYOffset) { //usual
            vertical_position = pageYOffset;
        }
        else if (document.documentElement.clientHeight)//ie
            vertical_position = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        else if (document.body)//ie quirks
            vertical_position = document.body.scrollTop;
        b_search.style.top = vertical_position + Math.round(0.85 * window.innerHeight);
        b_clear.style.top = vertical_position + Math.round(0.85 * window.innerHeight);

        function updateButtonsTop() {
            if (pageYOffset) { //usual
                vertical_position = pageYOffset;
            }
            else if (document.documentElement.clientHeight)//ie
                vertical_position = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            else if (document.body)//ie quirks
                vertical_position = document.body.scrollTop;

            if (buttons_div.offsetTop > 0.85 * window.innerHeight) {
                if (buttons_div.offsetTop >= b_search.offsetTop) {
                    if ( buttons_div.offsetTop >= (vertical_position + Math.round(0.85 * window.innerHeight)) ) {
                        b_search.style.top = vertical_position + Math.round(0.85 * window.innerHeight);
                        b_clear.style.top = vertical_position + Math.round(0.85 * window.innerHeight);
                    } else {
                        b_search.style.top = buttons_div.offsetTop;
                        b_clear.style.top = buttons_div.offsetTop;
                    }
                }
            }
            if( b_search.style.top > buttons_div.offsetTop ) {
                b_search.style.top = buttons_div.offsetTop;
                b_clear.style.top = buttons_div.offsetTop;
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener("wheel", updateButtonsTop);
        document.addEventListener("scroll", updateButtonsTop);
    </h:outputScript>
```

```css
.clear { 
  clear: both; 
  float: none; 
  font-size: 0px; 
  height: 0px; 
  background: none; 
  padding: 0!important; 
}

.center { 
  text-align: center; 
}

.ui-button { 
  vertical-align: top; 
  border: medium none; 
}
```

```html
    <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="search-and-clear-btns" class="center" style="display: inline-block">
    <p:button id="search" value="Search" title="Search" href="#search" style="position: absolute;"/>
    <p:button id="clear" styleClass="button-second" value="Clear" href="#clear" title="Clear" style="margin-left: 201px; position: absolute;"/>
  </div>
```

On my page it's exactly on the left side.

SOLVED BY:

adding in js script:

```
        b_search.style.left = Math.round(window.innerWidth / 2) - Math.round((2*b_search.offsetWidth+40)/2);
        b_clear.style.left = Math.round(window.innerWidth / 2) - Math.round((2*b_clear.offsetWidth+40)/2);
```

40 that I add in second Math.round is the space between buttons.

Answer (score 0):

To center with margins auto, the element must be position relative. In order to solve in your code, you have inline-block, so don't fit in the entire horizontal page. You change to block and it works.

```
 .center {
     display: block;
     text-align : center;
  }
```

The buttons are absolute positioning, another error. What are you trying with it?

```
  <p:button id="search" value="Search" title="Search" href="#search"/>
```

Good luck

Comment: The absolute positioning let me make these buttons moveable when scrolling the page. Just added the js code that updates buttons.

Comment: What don't you use position:fixed and you save all of this javascript? Another thing is that if you use absolute/fixed positioning you can't center with this code the buttons. You must to center the parent div and forget the text-align:Center

Comment: When I'm using posiiton:fixed I cant stick this div where I want to, that's why I've decided to write JS script to make that. I don't know if I understand correctly, I have to remove text-align:center from search-and-clear-btns div?

Comment: I see that you solved with javascript. Is less performance but it works.